# Use reticulate to access an R object in a new environment

Tags: r, reticulate

The following gives the expected result (executed in the global environment):

```r
library(reticulate)

x <- 1
py_run_string("r.x = 2")

#> x
#[1] 2
```

However, when I try to access an object from a new environment, the python code is "run" in my global environment instead:

```r
library(reticulate)
e <- new.env()
assign("y", 1, e)

eval(py_run_string("r.y = 2"), envir = e)

#> e$y
#[1] 1
#> y
#[1] 2
```

Is there any way to manipulate an object from a separate R environment with python code? Maybe `reticulate` isn't the correct tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing. Based on this [response](https://community.rstudio.com/t/reticulate-py-run-and-local-environments-in-r/46341) from R Studio, I believe that the `r` object in `reticulate` only accesses `.GlobalEnv`.